# Why in a relation one to many (1-N) always primary key one side put inside N side can we do vice-versa?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I'm working on a project, but I have a problem with the designing database. I would like to know about why in a relation 1 to N always primary key one side put inside N side can we do vice-versa?

For example, we have two tables `User` and `Comment`; in these tables we have to put the primary key of `User` into the `Comment` table as a foreign key. Can we do vice-versa?

For example, I put primary key of `Comment` table into the `User` table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect your User table is intended to have one row per user but there are potentially multiple comments per user. So if you put the comment foreign key values in the User table you would need a way to add multiple comments into a single row, perhaps using something like a multiple valued data structure, an array or a nested table.

Many database systems do support "complex" attributes of that kind, but not all, so a lot depends on which technology you are using. If complex types are allowed by your software then the methods to access them potentially involve more complexity than accessing single values for an attribute. In a relational database relational operations treat attributes as single values and that's why in relational database design the referencing foreign key attribute belongs in the Comment table.